# Python -- Save Objects Together in a Binary File?

Tags: python

I have a `python` class that contains many objects -- some are data structures (`lists`, `dicts` etc) and some are handlers to other classes (that also contain other data structures...).

Rather than using `pickle` to save the entire class & its contents, I was wondering if there is a way to `serialize` the data of *several desired objects* and save them (ONLY them) in a binary file?

For example, suppose that I have the following 2 python objects:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
myDict = {'a' : 14, 'b' : 5, 'c' : 65}
```

What is the best way to save the contents of BOTH of these `python` objects in a **binary file**? ideally, I'd like to save *both objects* in the same binary file, and be able to load the data later on.

Comment: You can try to build something using the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module but it doesn't support saving lists or dicts as far as I know.

Comment: If they're really as simple as lists or dicts, consider json, as layed out in [How I can I read multiple JSON objects from a file/stream in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886283/how-i-can-i-read-multiple-json-objects-from-a-file-stream-in-python).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then create a container class for them (or named tuple, or just a tuple, whatever) and pickle it (or modify the original class so that only those parts that you want are pickled). `pickle` *is* serialisation, and it is the standard Python mechanism to do it. So unless you need e.g. more interoperability between different languages, stick to it.

Comment: Thank you. does `pickle` save data in an economical way? (I expect to deal with big objecs)

Comment: @user3262424: Use protocol 2, it's currently the most compact/efficient format.

Comment: In Python 3, there's protocol 3 which is still more efficient. In general, passing `-1` as the protocol argument will always use the most recent protocol (but may not be backwards compatible).

Comment: @ThomasK: Ah, yes. I still mentally default to Python 2. If the data is persisted for long periods of time, it may be best to specify the protocol explicitly, though.

Comment: I'm starting to use Python 3 more, although my fingers still tend to go `print x`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pickle

imelda = ('More Mayhem', 
        'Imelda May', 
        '2011',
         ((1, 'Pulling the Rug')
         (2, 'Psycho'),
         (3, 'Mayhem'),
         (4, 'Kentish Town Waltz')))

with open("imelda.pickle", "wb") as pickle_file:
    pickle.dumps(imelda, pickle_file)
```

Comment: Please add some description describing the code answer