# How can I parse the first JSON object on a stream in JS

Tags: javascript, json

I have a stream of JSON objects, as with JSON-RPC over TCP or WebSockets. There's no length prefix or delimiter, because JSON is self-delimiting. So, when I read from the stream, I may end up with something like this:

```
{"id":1,"result":{"answer":23},"error":null}
{"id":2,"result":{"answer":42},"error":null}
{"id":3,"result":{"answ
```

I need to parse each JSON object one by one. I can't do this with JSON.parse, because it will just throw a syntax error for extraneous data at the end.

Of course with that example I could go line by line, but I can't rely on the whitespace looking like that; JSON-RPC can just as easily look like this:

```
{
  "id": 1, 
  "result": {
    "answer": 23
  },
  "error":null
}
```

Or this:

```
{"id":1,"result":{"answer":23},"error":null}{"id":2,"result":{"answer":42},"error":null}
```

With most parsers in other languages, the obvious answer is something like this (using Python as an example):

```
buf = ''
decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
def onReadReady(sock):
  buf += sock.read()
  obj, index = decoder.raw_decode(buf)
  buf = buf[index:]
  if obj:
    dispatch(obj)
```

But I can't find anything similar in JS. I've looked at every JS parser I can find, and they're all effectively equivalent to JSON.parse.

I tried looking at various JSON-RPC frameworks to see how they handle this problem, and they just don't. Many of them assume that a recv will always return exactly one send (which works fine for JSON-RPC over HTTP, but not over TCP or WebSockets—although it may appear to work in local tests, of course). Others don't actually handle JSON-RPC because they add requirements on whitespace (some of which aren't even valid for JSON-RPC).

I could write a delimiter check that balances brackets and quotes (handling escaping and quoting, of course), or just write a JSON parser from scratch (or port one from another language, or modify http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/), but I can't believe no one has done this before.

EDIT: I've made two versions myself, http://pastebin.com/fqjKYiLw based on json-sans-eval, and http://pastebin.com/8H4QT82b based on Crockford's reference recursive descent parser json_parse.js. I would still prefer to use something that's been tested and used by other people rather than coding it myself, so I'm leaving this question open.

Comment: So, you want to parse JSON streams like SAX parses XML?

Comment: No, not really. I don't want callbacks on each subobject in the hierarchy, I just want to get each top-level object. (I suppose a SAX parser would be sufficient to build what I want, but it's definitely not necessary.)

Comment: I think typical json-rpc returns a single object as the payload. Is this a custom backend that you wrote? If you control it I'd probably add a new delimiter or maybe use [netstrings](http://cr.yp.to/proto/netstrings.txt).

Comment: Yes, JSON-RPC returns a single object as the payload, but that doesn't mean anything over TCP or WebSockets, because they don't have any concept of payload, just a stream. JSON-RPC doesn't have any delimiter between payloads because it's self-delimiting—as long as you have a rawDecode style function. Which is why I want one.

Comment: And adding an extra delimiter (and escaping it within the JSON), or doing JSON-RPC over netstrings over sockets instead of JSON-RPC directly over sockets (which is the same thing as using a length prefix, which I mentioned earlier), or anything similar means it's not JSON-RPC anymore, which means I can't use standard or off-the-shelf JSON-RPC code for all of the other components.

Comment: I still can't find anything, 9 years later... python has a nice JSONDecoder with a raw_decode method which returns how much of the input was left over.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After a month of searching for alternatives and not finding anything useful, I decided to code up a bunch of different implementations and test them out, and I went with my modification of Crockford's reference recursive-descent parser (as described in the question, [available here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/fb2d5072-5b3c-4fea-83f9-256392b9b77d/view-source)).

It wasn't the fastest, but it was more than fast enough in every test I did. More importantly, it catches clearly erroneous JSON, when that's not ambiguous with incomplete JSON, much better than most of the other alternatives. Most importantly, it required very few, and pretty simple, changes from a well-known and -tested codebase, which makes me more confident in its correctness.

Still, if anyone knows of a better library than mine (and just being used by lots of projects instead of just me would count as a major qualification), I'd love to know about it.

Comment: try{x=JSON.parse(buff);buff="";}catch(y){buff=getCurrentBuff(); continue;}

Comment: @dandavis: No, because `JSON.parse` will fail if you give it 1-1/2 JSON objects, so this can't possibly work. That's already explained at the top of the question.

Comment: @abarent: yeah, but we can ignore the failures, laud the successes, and can try every possible slice permutation of a buffer (0)-(0,-1) in milliseconds... ugly? maybe. effective? very much so. i can count from one and a half to two fast, but nowhere near as fast as js. just keep on "try"ing until you get something.  literally. you can go char-by-char, or skip ahead to braces. it cannot fail! in a related application, as a noob i used a loop+try to find complete functions in the middle of a string of code, not even knowing what an ast or parser even was...

Comment: @dandavis: That would be _incredibly_ slow. If your average message is, say, 10KB, you're parsing 10K times as often as you need to. So each message now takes tens of seconds to process, instead of milliseconds. That's not even close to acceptable.

Comment: @abernert: actually, by splitting on braces, i was able to find valid chunks with an average of 12 guesses, each of which took well less than 1ms to attempt. if 800 data events per second is incredibly slow to you, you need to lower your expectations considerably. Also consider that JSON.parse runs in C, whereas a user-land parser will run a lot slower.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple JSON Object separator. It assumes that you receive a series of JSON objects (not array) and that are well formed.

```
function JSONObjectSepaator() {

    this.onObject = function (JSONStr) {};

    this.reset = function () {
        this.brace_count = 0;
        this.inString = false;
        this.escaped = false;
        this.buffer = "";
    };

    this.receive = function (S) {
        var i;
        var pos=0;
        for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++) {
            var c = S[i];
            if (this.inString) {
                if (this.escaped) {
                    this.escaped = false;
                } else {
                    if (c == "\\") {
                        this.escaped = true;
                    } else if (c == "\"") {
                        this.inString = false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (c == "{") {
                    this.brace_count++;
                } else if (c == "}") {
                    this.brace_count--;
                    if (this.brace_count === 0) {
                        this.buffer += S.substring(pos,i+1);
                        this.onObject(this.buffer);
                        this.buffer = "";
                        pos=i+1;
                    }
                } else if (c == "\"") {
                    this.inString = true;                   
                } 
            }
        }
        this.buffer += S.substring(pos);
    };

    this.reset();
    return this;
}
```

To use it, you can do it this way:

```
var separator = new JSONObjectSepaator();
separator.onObject = function (o) {
    alert("Object received: "+o);
};

separator.receive('{"id":1,"result":{"answer":23},"error":null, "x');
separator.receive('x":"\\\""}{"id":2,"result":{"answer":42},"error":null}{"id":');
separator.receive('3,"result":{"answer":43},"err{or":3}');
```

Comment: From a quick test, this is a whole lot slower than the other two implementations. It seems possible that that's only because it's appending characters one at a time, instead of holding off on the `buffer +=` bit until we either get balanced braces or reach the end of `S`, and if we fix that it'll actually be significantly faster. But that's just a guess, and I don't have time to test now. (I'll also compare it to the similar code I wrote early and then backed off of, although all these months later I don't remember why I gave up on it, so I'm not sure how much good that will do.)

Comment: @abarnert I made the optimization of changing buffer += bit to add whole blocks. It improved the algorithm by 20%. I also pass the responsibility of parsing each object to the callback function. (80% of the time was spend in parsing the individual objects). As a side note, remark that JSON.parse is 80% faster than eval.

Comment: Be careful about claims like "JSON.parse is 80% faster than eval". That varies wildly between different JS implementations, and even different versions of the same implementation. Try it with trivial JSON in Gecko 3.5 vs. 5.0 vs. 6.0, for example… Anyway, fortunately, I only care about a single JS engine (for this app), and I have relatively consistent data, so doing realistic tests shouldn't be hard once I get a chance. Thanks.

Comment: I tested every thing in chrome for mac version 28.0.1500.95. ;) , and the test that i did was just run the example use 1000000 times. The comment is probable out of scope and too generic, but i put that comment becouse it surprissed me the big difference between the two implementations. Thank you for the apreciation.

Comment: OK, I ran my test suite on Gecko 14 (the engine I happen to care about at the moment). The character-by-character version takes 180%-2900% as long as the other implementation… but the buffering version is 30%-180%. And it seems to win biggest on the tests with very large or complex JSON, which is likely to be exactly when performance matters. In the app I'm currently working on, the performance is good enough, and the benefit of keeping code that's been tested and deployed for over a year wins… but I will definitely revisit this in the future. Again, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pragmatic answer: use python

```
    pos = 0
    try:
        while not pos == len(str(body)):
            # raw_decode will parse as much of the line as possible and return how much was left
            j, json_len = decoder.raw_decode(str(body)[pos:])
            pos += json_len
            # "j" holds your object
```

I'm writing some code to parse large numbers of JSON files saved from streams which have from 1 to 50 JSON objects in each one. *This is a JavaScript hack* but it works for my purposes (relies on the error message containing the position of the "bad" JSON. If the error character is a "{" then I know it's probably the start of a new object):

```
    let contents = ""; // your JSON string
    let startIndex = 0;
    let endIndex = contents.length;

    do {
        let obj;
        try {
            let str = contents.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
            obj = JSON.parse(str);
            startIndex = endIndex;
            endIndex = contents.length;
            console.log("successfully parsed", obj);
        }
        catch (e) {
            let match = e.toString().match(/^SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position (\d+)$/);
            if (match && match.length == 2) {
                endIndex = parseInt(match[1]) + startIndex;
            }
            else throw e;
        }
    } while (startIndex < endIndex);
```