# How can I access this result

Tags: jquery, json

I have this result from my server and I want to access the value of mem and pid

```
{"mem":"7","pid":"5"}{"mem":"9","pid":"7"}{"mem":"10","pid":"7"}{"mem":"8","pid":"5"}
```

I tried echo the value from my console.but it did not show.

```
 $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                dataType:'json',
                data:'mydata'
                url:'tomyurl',
                success:function(data){
                 console.log(data[0].mem);//did not show the value


                   });
```

**EDIT**

here is my server side script

```
  public function display_children($parent,$level){
 try {
          $cmd = $this->connection->prepare('SELECT mem,pid from mytree where pid = ?');

          $cmd->execute(array($parent));


          $results = array(
              'mem' => array(),
              'pid' => array()

          );

          while ( $row =  $cmd->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {


              $results['mem']=$row['mem'];
              $results['pid']=$row['pid'];

              echo json_encode(results);
              $this->display_children($row['mem'], $level + 1);

          }


      }
      catch(PDOException $ex){
          return $ex->getMessage();
      }

  }
```

I followed here on how to query  [hierarchical-data-database](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/)

and I'm having problem in accessing the value of my mem and pid.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: data shown is invalid format for json. Are you sure that's exactly how it is received? If so it needs to be modified to be array of objects. Should look like `[{"mem":"7","pid":"5"},{"mem":"9","pid":"7"}]`

Comment: Related: [How can I parse the first JSON object on a stream in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829811/how-can-i-parse-the-first-json-object-on-a-stream-in-js?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid JSON as written.  You probably want to ensure that your server is returning a valid array, like:

`[{"mem":"7","pid":"5"},{"mem":"9","pid":"7"},{"mem":"10","pid":"7"},{"mem":"8","pid":"5"}]`

If it is, the code you've supplied should work.  To get all the `mem` and `pid` values in the array, you can do something like:

```
for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    var item = data[index];
    console.log("index=" + index + ", pid=" + item.pid + ", mem=" + item.mem);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cn7mzxws/1/

Since you're using jQuery, you can also use [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to accomplish the same thing.

Though if you only care about the `mem` value for the first item, then `data[0].mem` is correct, once your data is correctly packed into a JSON-array.

Comment: ,how can I returned valid array in my query ? I posted my php script.