# How to read line-delimited JSON from large file (line by line)

Tags: python, json, parsing, large-files

I'm trying to load a large file (2GB in size) filled with JSON strings, delimited by newlines. Ex:

```
{
    "key11": value11,
    "key12": value12,
}
{
    "key21": value21,
    "key22": value22,
}
…
```

The way I'm importing it now is:

```
content = open(file_path, "r").read() 
j_content = json.loads("[" + content.replace("}\n{", "},\n{") + "]")
```

Which seems like a hack (adding commas between each JSON string and also a beginning and ending square bracket to make it a proper list).

Is there a better way to specify the JSON delimiter (newline `\n` instead of comma `,`)?

Also, `Python` can't seem to properly allocate memory for an object built from 2GB of data, is there a way to construct each `JSON` object as I'm reading the file line by line? Thanks!

Comment: just read each line and construct a json object at this time

Comment: @njzk2: I think the problem is that there are newlines inside the JSON objects, not just between them, right?

Comment: there are newlines between the JSON objects, and inside of them, yes. The replace function works because the only places where a newline separates a closing and opening curly brace ("}" and "{") is between objects. I'd still like to not rely on it to load the JSON.

Comment: @Arkady, Cat: see the end of my answer, someone wrote a parser that account that sort of things, I think that should solve your issue.

Answer (score 46):

Just read each line and construct a json object at this time:

```
with open(file_path) as f:
    for line in f:
        j_content = json.loads(line)
```

This way, you load proper complete json object (provided there is no `\n` in a json value somewhere or in the middle of your json object) and you avoid memory issue as each object is created when needed.

There is also this answer.:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7795029/671543

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, @njzk2 the code you wrote doesn't quite work though: `json.loads` raises an exception if you call it on a partial JSON string...

Comment: yes, hence my comment `provided there is no \n (...) in the middle of your json object`. Otherwise, the link I added points to an answer with a parser that works with your scenario.

Comment: `json.loads` fails because there are no commas between the JSON objects, irrespective of newlines being present or not...

Comment: No. `json.loads` fails because the line does not contain a complete jsonobject. `for line in f` loops on the lines of you file. If a line does not contain a complete jsonobject (such as if it is split on several lines), it fails.

Comment: Alternatively and perhaps concisely,`[json.loads(line) for line in f]` could make code in oneline and possible for nesting in future.

Answer (score 11):

```
contents = open(file_path, "r").read() 
data = [json.loads(str(item)) for item in contents.strip().split('\n')]
```

Answer (score 7):

This will work for the specific file format that you gave. If your format changes, then you'll need to change the way the lines are parsed.

```
{
    "key11": 11,
    "key12": 12
}
{
    "key21": 21,
    "key22": 22
}
```

Just read line-by-line, and build the JSON blocks as you go:

```
with open(args.infile, 'r') as infile:

    # Variable for building our JSON block
    json_block = []

    for line in infile:

        # Add the line to our JSON block
        json_block.append(line)

        # Check whether we closed our JSON block
        if line.startswith('}'):

            # Do something with the JSON dictionary
            json_dict = json.loads(''.join(json_block))
            print(json_dict)

            # Start a new block
            json_block = []
```

If you are interested in parsing one very large JSON file without saving everything to memory, you should look at using the object_hook or object_pairs_hook callback methods in the json.load API.

Answer (score 5):

This expands [Cohen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61184208/1810559)'s answer:

```
content_object = s3_resource.Object(BucketName, KeyFileName)
file_buffer = io.StringIO()
file_buffer = content_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')

json_lines = []
for line in file_buffer.splitlines():
    j_content = json.loads(line)
    json_lines.append(j_content)

df_readback = pd.DataFrame(json_lines)
```

This assumes that the entire file will fit in memory. If it is too big then this will have to be modified to read in chunks or use [Dask](https://dask.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Had to read some data from AWS S3 and parse a newline delimited jsonl file. My solution was this using `splitlines`

The code:

```
for line in json_input.splitlines():
     one_json = json.loads(line)
```

Comment: `splitlines` is not safe for JSON Lines, it can split a JSON line in the middle if there are strings with certain characters, such as `NEL` (`0x85`).

Comment: Didn't know that, has worked for me for a long long time but good to know I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The line by line reading approach is good, as mentioned in some of the above answers.

However across multiple `JSON` tree structures I would recommend decomposition into 2 functions to have more robust error handling.

For example,

```
def load_cases(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as file:
        cases = (parse_case_line(json.loads(line)) for line in file)
        cases = filter(None, cases)
        return list(cases)
```

`parse_case_line` can encapsulate the key parsing logic required in your above example, for example with regex matching, or application-specific requirements. It also means that you can select which json key-values you want to parse out.

Another advantage of this approach is `filter` handles multiple `\n` in the middle of your json object, and parses the whole file :-).

Answer (score 0):

The jq python library makes quick work of handling cases like this.

Here's an example from my project. I had the file object from elsewhere in my case.

```py
import jq

raw = file.read().decode("utf-8")
for row in iter(jq.compile(".").input(text=raw)):
  print(row)
```

And the dependency can be installed as such:

```
pip install jq
```

Look into jq, it's an easy way to query json objects, on the command line or in code.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pandas 1.5.3:

```
pd.read_json( "path/to/json/delimited/file.json", lines=True )
```

Works for me ;)

[json delimited file + code to read it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24ZvB.png)

Answer (score -1):

Just read it line by line and parse e through a stream
while ur hacking trick  (adding commas between each JSON string and also a beginning and ending square bracket to make it a proper list) isn't memory-friendly if the file is too more than 1GB as the whole content will land on the RAM.