# Combine jq objects with distinct keys into single object without --slurp

Tags: python, json, jq

I have

```
{"a":1} {"b":2}
```

and I want to use `jq` to get

```
{"a": 1, "b":2}
```

`jq --slurp add myfile` works great. However, I want to use it with `jq.py`, which doesn't have `slurp` mode. Does `jq` have a way to do this for arbitrary sequences of objects (with distinct keys) without using `--slurp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Less demanding on memory than using [inputs] would be:

```
reduce inputs as $in ({}; . + $in)
```

The above assumes the -n command-line option is in effect.  If this is not possible with py.jq, then the following filter should be used instead:

```
reduce inputs as $in (.; . + $in)
```

p.s. 
Perhaps the author of py.jq will be willing to address the issue concerning command-line options if made aware of it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading myfile with python, the [`splitstream`](https://github.com/evolvIQ/splitstream) module [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31060923) may be what you want. Here is a test example (test.py) which uses [jq.py](https://github.com/mwilliamson/jq.py).

```
import splitstream
from jq import jq

def slurp(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for s in splitstream.splitfile(f, format="json"):
            yield s

obj = {}
for jstr in slurp('myfile'):
    obj = jq("[%s, .] | add" % obj).transform(text=jstr, text_output=True)

print obj
```

Here is a sample run

```
$ cat myfile
{"a":1}
{"b":2}

$ python test.py
{"a":1,"b":2}
```

Although this appears to do what you asked for using [jq.py](https://github.com/mwilliamson/jq.py) I don't think its a good solution because sharing the state between python and jq is clumsy and inefficient.

A better approach might be to use jq as a subprocess.  Here is an example (test2.py):

```
import json
import sh

cmd = sh.jq('-M', '-s', 'add', 'myfile')
obj = json.loads( cmd.stdout )
print json.dumps(obj, indent=2)
```

Sample run:

```
$ python test2.py
{
  "a": 1, 
  "b": 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This produces the desired output.

`jq -nc '[inputs] | add'`

I can't say if it would work with jq.py, however.

Comment: Assuming py.jq cannot be given the -n command line option, use '[., inputs] | add'