# How to read a huge JSON file one by one in Python 3?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a huge JSON file in the list form

```
{data 1}
{data 2}
{data 3}
...
```

I don't want to load the whole file but only each part one by one to parse, i.e. I first want to parse data1, then data2, ...

I know `json.loads()` in Python 3 but it seems to me that it needs an entire JSON string from the file.

Comment: In `.load`, [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/json/__init__.py) shows it indeed uses `return loads(fp.read())` – it reads the whole file at once. But (being unfamiliar with JSON *at all*) isn't it a problem that the *root object* must be parsed in its entirety anyway? You cannot do that if you can't read it entirely first.

Comment: In this case I know that the JSON file is stored in the list form, i.e. there is no root object. Not sure if I can integrate this knowledge to read each object one by one?

Comment: Is each JSON object on a separate line? Then you could just parse each line separately with `json.loads`.

Comment: Hi @JanneKarila: no, each object is in multiple lines.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886283/how-i-can-i-lazily-read-multiple-json-values-from-a-file-stream-in-python

Comment: If @JanneKarila's (very good) suggestion works, we can close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes I think it is a duplicated one.