# How I can I lazily read multiple JSON values from a file/stream in Rust?

Tags: json, serialization, rust

I'd like to read multiple JSON objects from a file/reader in Rust, one at a time. Unfortunately `serde_json::from_reader(...)` just reads until end-of-file; there doesn't seem to be any way to use it to read a single object or to lazily iterate over the objects.

Is there any way to do this? Using `serde_json` would be ideal, but if there's a different library I'd be willing use that instead.

At the moment I'm putting each object on a separate line and parsing them individually, but I would really prefer not to need to do this.

### Example Use

#### main.rs

```rust
use serde_json;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
   let stdin = std::io::stdin();
   let stdin = stdin.lock();

   for item in serde_json::iter_from_reader(stdin) {
     println!("Got {:?}", item);
   }

   Ok(())
}
```

#### in.txt

```
{"foo": ["bar", "baz"]} 1 2 [] 4 5 6
```

#### example session

```
Got Object({"foo": Array([String("bar"), String("baz")])})
Got Number(1)
Got Number(2)
Got Array([])
Got Number(4)
Got Number(5)
Got Number(6)
```

Comment: When I came across this in the Serde docs as a built-in feature, I had to share, after [it having been such a pain to get this behaviour in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6886283/1114). :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was a pain when [I wanted to do it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6886283/1114), but fortunately in Rust this is a directly-supported feature of the de-facto-standard `serde_json` crate! It isn't exposed as a single convenience function, but we just need to create [a `serde_json::Deserializer`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.39/serde_json/struct.Deserializer.html) reading from our file/reader, then use its `.into_iter()` method to get [a `StreamDeserializer` iterator](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.39/serde_json/struct.StreamDeserializer.html) yielding `Result`s containing `serde_json::Value` JSON values.

```rust
use serde_json; // 1.0.39

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    let stdin = stdin.lock();

    let deserializer = serde_json::Deserializer::from_reader(stdin);
    let iterator = deserializer.into_iter::<serde_json::Value>();
    for item in iterator {
        println!("Got {:?}", item?);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

One thing to be aware of: if a syntax error is encountered, the iterator will start to produce an infinite sequence of error results and never move on. You need to make sure you handle the errors inside of the loop, or the loop will never end. In the snippet above, we do this by using the `?` question mark operator to break the loop and return the first `serde_json::Result::Err` from our function.

Comment: Leving ths comment just to thank Jeremy for comming here living this version of a question he asked 8 YEARS ago and saving my undergraduate a*s. Thank you Jeremy. Stay safe

Comment: It still reads whole file and prints whole file contents at once inside loop. Did you try this with a properly formatted JSON file ?